# override with new function declaration syntax

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the new function declaration syntax introduced in C++11, it is easy to translate a member function from:

```
std::unique_ptr<...> operator()() const;
```

to

```
auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<...>;
```

I believe that to add override to the first you would write:

```
std::uniqe_ptr<...> operator()() const override;
```

When I write:

```
auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<...> override;
```

Clang gives the error:

```
error: type-id cannot have a name
auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<...> override
                                                ^~~~~~~~
```

When I write:

```
auto operator()() const override -> std::unique_ptr<...>;
```

Clang gives the error:

```
error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
auto operator()() const override -> std::unique_ptr<...>;
^
```

Where would you put override in the new syntax?

Comment: Latest version on windows from http://llvm.org/builds/ - based on  SVN r190317.

Comment: This compiles without errors on GCC 4.8.1: `auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<int> override {}`

Comment: VC++2012 compiles `auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<int> override`, too.

Comment: Actually, according to the grammar, the first form is correct, and clang-bot on #llvm (which is based on trunk) also compiles it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the syntax, the `override` keyword should be after the trailing return type, i.e., you'd use

```
auto operator()() -> std::unique_ptr<int> override;
```

Trying it with a recent snapshot of gcc works while even a recent version of clang fails. I'd say this is a bug in clang's implementation.

The relevant quote from the standard is 8.4.1 [dcl.fct.def.general] paragraph 1:

> Function definitions have the form

```
function-definition:
    attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt declarator virt-specifier-seqopt   function-body
function-body:
    ctor-initializeropt compound-statement
function-try-block
= default ;
= delete ;
```

The `virt-specifier-seqopt` consists of `final` and/or `override`.

Comment: This just feels wrong.

Comment: @Xeo: well, it may feel wrong but this seems to be a reasonable place to put the these special keywords: the need to be in a location where nothing else can show up. Admittedly, this would also be the case between the closing parenthesis and the arrow...

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking it should be after cv- and ref-qualifiers, logically.

Comment: I am wondering why the auto keyword is in front of the expression. If I have a -> 'rettype', this type must be used and not auto. Can someone explain what is the sense of auto here? Thanks!